# How to exclude Sticky from Recent Post?

Tags: wp-query, exclude

Im sorry about my english.

I using below code to display recent post in my footer. The problem is, my recent post show sticky post. How to hide or remove sticky post from recent post??

```
<div class="footer_rct">

<?php $recent = new WP_Query("showposts=5"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
    <div class="footer_recent_item">

        <div class="footer_rct_images">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('img100'); ?></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/nophoto.png" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div class="footer_rct_tit_img">

            <div class="footer_rct_tit">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php $tit = the_title('','',FALSE); echo substr($tit, 0, 46); if (strlen($tit) > 46) echo " [...]"; ?>
            </a>
            </div>

            <!--<date>-->
            <div class="blog_date">

            <div class="blog_date_3">
            <?php the_time('M jS, Y') ?>
            </div>

            </div>
            <!--</date>-->

        </div>


    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$args = array( 
           'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 
           'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        );
$recent = new WP_Query( $args );
```

to exclude the sticky posts. You can read more about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts) in the Codex.

Comment: you're welcome, if that solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted. See howto [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).